# Should it be possible to use a StoreGeneratedPattern of Computed on a DateTimeOffset column with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odp.net

If I have a table in an Oracle DB with a `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE` column called LastModified and I wish to model it using EntityFramework; should it be possible to mark that column as DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed?

I have the aforementioned table and have successfully used EF6 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client to create a model first/db first edmx model. In line with the documentation, the `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE` column gets mapped as a DateTimeOffset and I've manually marked LastModified as Computed.

This works fine for SELECT statements but when I try and do an update, I get the following error:

> A store-generated value of type 'System.DateTime' could not be
>   converted to a value of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' required for
>   member 'LastModified' of type ....

Drilling down into the exception and stack trace yields:

> Invalid cast from 'System.DateTime' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'.
>
> at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType,
>   IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   System.DateTime.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider
>   provider)    at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type
>   conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.PropagatorResult.AlignReturnValue(Object
>   value, EdmMember member)

I spent a bit of time looking at the EntityFramework source and it seems like the code which deals with returning database generated values doesn't use the same mapping logic as the SELECT or Model Creation logic.

This results in `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE` being mapped to a DateTime when retrieved from the database as a database generated value and then failing when trying to convert that to a DateTimeOffset.

Is this known/expected behaviour? Have I missed a setting somewhere? Or is there only a limited subset of types that can be used as when using a StoreGeneratedPatten which isn't "None"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having debugged EntityFramework and eventually bypassing it altogether, I've discovered that the problem lies with the provider (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client). An UPDATE through EntityFramework on a table with a `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE` computed column generates sql like below:

```
DECLARE "COLUMNC_FOROUTPUT" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE;

BEGIN
  UPDATE "SCHEMA"."TABLEA"
  SET "COLUMNB" = :p0
  WHERE ("COLUMNA" = :p1)
  RETURNING "COLUMNC" INTO "COLUMNC_FOROUTPUT";

  OPEN :p2 FOR 
  SELECT "COLUMNC_FOROUTPUT" AS "COLUMNC_FOROUTPUT" FROM dual;
END;
```

where `:p2` is a REF CURSOR. If the above sql and appropriate parameters are fed direct to ODP.Net, then using `ExecuteReader()` and `reader.GetFieldValue<object>(0)` yields an object with a type of `DateTime` which is contrary to what `TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIMEZONE` should map to (DateTimeOffset).

I guess another question is needed regarding ODP.Net, REF CURSORS and TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE mappings specifically as the answer to my original question appears to be "Yes but not if you're using the latest version of Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client as a provider".

### UPDATE

Actually it makes no difference if a ref cursor is involved, the problem lies within the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleTypeMapper class which maps Timestamp with TZ to DateTime and not DateTimeOffset. This will affect any call to GetFieldValue on an OracleDataReader.

I have asked a [question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3939350) on the ODP.Net forums to see whether anyone can confirm if this is correct behaviour.